# Build() or Update() can only be called once on a ContainerBuilder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, autofac

We are currently using autofac in our mvc web app.

```
Build() or Update() can only be called once on a ContainerBuilder
```

Every 1-4 days we get the error noted above. It's driving me crazy. I've been trying to see why it would be doing this but I can't pinpoint the issue.

Can someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Where are you calling it?

Comment: on application start. I think we've tracked down the issue to being , since it usually happens early in am or on weekends, when 2 users hit the site at the same time call the startup process and invoke build at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same thing in my application (.Net Core 3.1)
I wanted to get the Container and resolve registered services.

In .Net Core 3.1 you can't simply change `Startup.ConfigureServices` method to return `IServiceProvider` as it was in previous versions

So, to get the services you need in your Startup `void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)` method call `app.ApplicationServices.GetAutofacRoot()` this will return ILifetimeScope instance you can use to resolve services

Note. Consider that saving this instance globally is not the best practice

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            //app middleware registrations 
            //...
            //

            ILifetimeScope autofacRoot = app.ApplicationServices.GetAutofacRoot();
            var repository = autofacRoot.Resolve<IRepository>();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have start-up processes that require HttpApplication resources, I would recommend removing application initialization to a static constructor or a completely separate singleton.  I have seen similar issues with `Application_Start()`, you need a structure that is guaranteed to be called just once.